# MonoTouch 4: The type or namespace name 'Outlet' could not be found

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have purchased MonoTouch last October from Novell. Now that I updated to MonoDevelop 2.8.5, and XCode 4.2, my projects won't build because the designer files complain:

> The type or namespace name 'Outlet' could not be found

I have Monotouch 4.0.3, and just read in the [Transitioning to XCode 4](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/transitioning_from_xcode_3_to_xcode_4) article that Monotouch 4.0.4.1 or greater is required for XCode 4 support. When I try to update Monotouch, I can only find a MonoTouch 5 dmg, but it complains my current license does not allow me to upgrade to MonoTouch 5 (a natural thing because it now belongs to Xamarin)

So you could help me out with either of the two:

1. Tell me how I can download MonoTouch 4.0.4.1 or greater (but less than 5 due to licensing - I do not want to buy a new license)
2. How I can fix the problem of namespace during build

Any directions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tell me how I can download MonoTouch 4.0.4.1 or greater

Please contact support@xamarin.com

They will be able to validate your license and allow you to download all/any versions you are entitled for.

> How I can fix the problem of namespace during build

I don't think you can, without updating to 4.0.4.1, if you used Xcode's interface builder to develop your user interfaces.

Comment: They did in fact reply within 12 hours, on a Christmas holiday, sending me a 4.0.6 link.

Comment: So, working (at least for now) versions of components:  - MonoDevelop 2.8.5  
- MonoTouch 4.0.6  
- XCode 4.2

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop 2.8 is meant to be used with MonoTouch 5 (and Xcode 4.2), while MonoDevelop 2.6 is for MonoTouch 4.

This is an unfortunate artifact of the changes required in MonoDevelop to properly support iOS 5 (they were substantial, and the extra work required to be backwards compatible with older versions of MonoTouch was deemed to be too big).